# How to render the javascript page in portia?

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, scrapy, portia, scrapinghub

I am using the portia for rendering the JavaScript page using scrapinghub/splash middleware. but its seem following error during loading job page in portia.

Error:

> Your web browser must have JavaScript enabledin order for this
>   application to display correctly.

Platform: portia-scrapy + scrapinghub/splash.

Please let me know how to resolve this error in mozila firefox.

Note:
Also i have tried following instruction :

```
1. In the address bar, type about:config and press Enter.
2. Click "I'll be careful, I promise" if a warning message appears.
3. In the search box, search for javascript.enabled
Toggle the "javascript.enabled" preference (right-click and select "Toggle" or double-click the preference) to change the value from "false" to "true".
```

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no official support for using splash in conjunction with Portia but adding support for it is a high priority.

https://github.com/scrapinghub/portia/issues/2

If you would like to use splash for simply rendering the page you can do so by adding the splash middleware to the Portia projects settings.

Comment: Yes, I am using the splash middleware inside the scrapy folder, but its getting the error "Your web browser must have JavaScript enabledin order for this application to display correctly.". thank you

Comment: How have you configured splash within your project?

Comment: DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'xxxx.middleware.splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
}

Comment: It looks like your settings aren't being imported into slyd. To do this you can create a new file called `local_settings.py` and have it import all of your settings from your spider `from xxxxx.settings import *` then it should also be used by the spider within the Portia UI

Comment: Please let me know could i posted it in "portia-master\slyd\slyd\local_settings" or ""portia-master\slyd\local_settings"".. I have tried both way. its seem same error tooo..

Comment: /slyd/slyd/local_settings.py . Did you check that the settings were loaded? Do you know that your SPLASH_URL_PASS is set correctly?